# Chatbot is unable to access Facebook users public profile

Tags: facebook-graph-api, botframework

My Facebook App (type business) is a chatbot developed with Microsoft Bot Framework (V4) and has the following granted permissions:

- pages_messaging advanced access
- public_profile advanced access

Users start the conversation with my chatbot by clicking a "Send to Messenger" button. This works.

As soon as I try to add some logic to get public user details (like firstname), this only works when the Facebook page owner is logged in, but not for other users.

the url I use to fetch the data:
`https://graph.facebook.com/<users page scoped id>?fields=first_name&access_token=<page access token>`

When I use the constructed url for other users in a browser I get

```
error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '<users page scoped id>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "<fb trace id>"
   }
}
```

Do I need more permissions or do I miss something else?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile: _“To retrieve a user’s profile information, you need to have Advanced Access for the Business Asset User Profile Access feature.”_ - do you?

Comment: nope, completely missed that one. Will start the request process. Tnx!

Comment: Feature request approved and problem solved.Thank you @CBroe